# Selenium Python: Census ACS Data- unable to select Download button in window

Tags: python, selenium, acs

I am attempting to scrape the Census website for ACS data.  I have scripted the whole processes using Selenium except the very last click. I am using Python. I need to click a download button that is in a window that pops when the data is zipped and ready, but I can't seem to identify this button.  It also seems that the button might change names based on when it was last run, for example, yui-gen2, yui-gen3, etc so I am thinking I might need to account for this someone. Although I normally only see yui-gen2.

Also, the tag seems to be in a "span" which might be adding to my difficulty honing in on the button I need to click.

Please help if you can shed any light on this for me.

code snippet:
 #Refine search results to get tables

```
driver.find_element_by_id("prodautocomplete").send_keys("S0101")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id("prodsubmit").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id("check_all_btn_above").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id("dnld_btn_above").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
driver.find_element_by_id("yui-gen0-button").click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
driver.find_element_by_id("yui-gen2-button").click()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NFyb.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfwp1.jpg)

Comment: What XPath/CSS selector/tagname/etc. have you tried using so far?

Comment: I get the following xpath when I look at the source. It doesn't seem to work. //*[@id="yui-gen2-button"]   I have also tried xpath at various levels up.

Comment: It might be useful, for debugging purposes, to print the html of the page just before you try to click on the button to see if the element is really there. You can use `print(driver.page_source)`

Comment: Found the following in the page source using the print. <div class="ft"><span class="button-group"><span id="yui-gen2" class="yui-button yui-push-button"><span class="first-child"><button type="button" id="yui-gen2-button">Download</button></span></span><span id="yui-gen3" class="yui-button yui-push-button"><span class="first-child"><button type="button" id="yui-gen3-button">Cancel</button></span></span></span></div>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the HTML you provided, you should be able to use

```
driver.find_element_by_id("yui-gen2-button")
```

I know you said you tried it but you didn't say if it works at all or what error message you are getting. If that never works, you likely have an IFRAME that you need to switch to.

If it works sometimes but not consistently due to changing ID, you can use something like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[.='Download']")
```

Comment: I have tried your first suggestion.  The code completes and does not error out, however, the data never downloads.  Its like it never actually clicks on the button, but perhaps it does find it. I will give your second suggestion a try.

Comment: It seems that the button click was working. I added some code to check for the file in the temp folder and wait until it appears. This seems to have resolved the issue. So the issue didn't have to do with the click, it had to do with waiting for the file to download. The browser was closing immediately after the click and not giving enough time for the download.  I have another script that downloads data from another website - that one finishes on the click and the wait for file isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the element id, which as you pointed out varies, you can use XPath as Nogoseke mentioned or CSS Selector. Be careful to not make the XPath/selector too specific or reliant on changing values, in this case the element id. Rather than using the id in XPath, try expressing the XPath in terms of the DOM structure (tags):

```
//*/div/div/div/span/span/span/button[contains(text(),'Download')]
```

TIL you can validate your XPath by using the search function, rather than by running it in Selenium. I right-clicked the webpage, "inspect element", ctrl+f, and typed in the above XPath to validate that it is the Download button.

For posterity, if the above XPath is too specific, i.e. it is reliant on too many levels of the DOM structure, you can do something shorter, like

```
//*button[contains(text(),'Download')]
```

although, this may not be specific enough and may require an additional field, since there may be multiple buttons on the page with the 'Download' text.

Comment: Having an XPath (or CSS selector) with that many required levels is more likely to be very brittle since any change in the 7 levels specified will break that locator. You can test XPaths in the dev console using `$x("<xpath goes here>")` and test CSS selectors using `$$("<css selector goes here>")`.

Comment: @JeffC thanks, and I was thinking about adding that detail in about the path yesterday. For posterity, I will add it now

Answer (score 0):

On the code inspection view on Chrome you can right click on the item you want to find and copy the xpath. You can they find your element by xpath on Selenium.

Comment: This is the xpath I get. //*[@id="yui-gen2-button"] it doesn't seem to work